# Request PDF from remote server and print it from web

Tags: javascript, c#, pdf, asp.net-web-api

I have pdf files that get generated on a remote server. From my web app I need to be able to request these pdfs and some how start a print action from the browser. Is something like this possible using the new XMLHttpRequest 2 functionality as mentioned here http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/xhr2/

The remote server is using Web API for all request/responses. I figure there may be a way to stream the files to the browser to accomplish this.

Comment: load the pdf in browser than call window.print().

Comment: That won't work cross browser unfortunately.

Comment: don't access using ajax , access pdf file through browser window.open method, it will work.

Comment: There are security blocks with this due to my web app being at a differenet url than the pdfs. My web app is at app.example.com and the pdfs are on pdfs.example.com.

Comment: If there is still a way to do the window print method when the app and pdfs are on a different sub-domain then please let me know.